# Overwrite values in one column with values from another unless null PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery, m

| Index | Is MTO | ShouldBeMTO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | null |
| 2 | TRUE | null |
| 3 | TRUE | null |
| 4 | TRUE | null |
| 5 | FALSE | null |
| 6 | TRUE | TRUE |
| 7 | FALSE | TRUE |
| 8 | etc. | ... |

I have data like that; I want to overwrite `Is MTO` with values from `ShouldBeMTO` except when null. - e.g. lines 1 to 5 stay the same, line 7 goes from False to True

The `Merge columns` option concatenates columns with a delimiter. I was thinking of trying to replace null with something then XOR the columns but that's not quite what I want.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh it's super simple:

Add Column->Add Custom Column then

```
= if [ShouldBeMTO] = null then [Is MTO] else [ShouldBeMTO]
```

I was worried the syntax would look at entire columns of data but this is row-by row