# How can I iterate through columns and replace nulls with the values of other columns?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

My table looks something like this:

| A | B | C | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| valueA1 | valueB1 | valueC1 | null | null | null |
| valueA2 | valueB2 | valueC2 | valueX2 | valueY2 | valueZ2 |
| valueA3 | valueB3 | valueC3 | valueX3 | valueY3 | valueZ3 |
| valueA4 | valueB4 | valueC4 | null | null | null |
| valueA5 | valueB5 | valueC5 | valueX5 | valueY5 | valueZ5 |

What I want:

For each row in the table,

If valueX1 = null then replace with valueA1 else return valueX1

If valueY1 = null then replace with valueB1 else return valueY1

If valueZ1 = null then replace with valueC1 else return valueZ1

I only need to replace three specific columns with three other specific columns, so the column selection doesn't need to be dynamic here. The result of columns X, Y and Z will effectively be:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| valueA1 | valueB1 | valueC1 |
| valueX2 | valueY2 | valueZ2 |
| valueX3 | valueY3 | valueZ3 |
| valueA4 | valueB4 | valueC4 |
| valueX5 | valueY5 | valueZ5 |

Perhaps something with List.Accumulate and Table.ReplaceValue? I know I could just create three separate Table.ReplaceValue steps for each column pair, but I want to know if there is a way of doing this in a single step.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/67888617/6609896 . I'd just write it 3 times, it will be just as fast as iterating over a list of column names and applying to each, and mapping a function over 3 columns at once is more challenging

Comment: I agree with @Greedo.  Especially since you don't need this to be dynamic.  Just write the three replace Values line and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the Query editor. Following steps you can do for each column:

Select column X. In the Start tab, you have the "Replace Value". Click and fill in the value to search for (null) and type AAAA as the value to replace. All nulls should now become AAAA. If this is not the case, it might by you have null as text and you will need to put quotes around it!

Now go to the advanced editor and replace the AAAA with "each [A]"

End result of your edit should be like:

```
Table.ReplaceValue(#"Promoted Headers",null,each [A],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"X"})
```

#"Promoted Headers" has a different name for you, this is ok.

Enjoy!